# sqlldr WHEN clause

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to code a sqlldr.ctl file WHEN Clause to limit the records imported to those matching a portion of the current Schema's name.

The code I have (which does **NOT** work) is:

```
 LOAD DATA
 TRUNCATE INTO TABLE TMP_PRIM_ACCTS
 when REGION_NUM = substr(user,-3,3)
 Fields terminated by "|" Optionally enclosed by '"'
 Trailing NULLCOLS
  ( PORTFOLIO_ACCT,
    PRIMARY_ACCT_ID NULLIF (PRIMARY_ASSET_ID="NULL"),
    REGION_NUM    NULLIF (PARTITION_NUM="NULL")
  )
```

sqlldr returns:

```
 SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 3.
 Expecting quoted string or hex identifier, found "substr".
 when PARTITION_NUM = substr(user,-3,3)
```

I cannot put single quotes around "user", because that turns it into the literal string "user".  Can anyone explain how I can reference the "active" User in this WHEN Clause?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this? (now I can't make test with SQLLDR, but this is syntax I used for changing values):

```
when REGION_NUM = "substr(:user,-3,3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can. [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SUTIL/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL1115) only shows fixed values:

[image]

Trying to use an expression in `when` that clause (or in `nullif`; thought I'd try to see if you could cause a rejection based on null PK value) you just see the literal value in the log:

```
Table TMP_PRIM_ACCTS, loaded when REGION_NUM = 0X73756273747228757365722c2d332c3329(character 'substr(user,-3,3)')
```

which is sort of what you referred when you said you couldn't quote `user`, but you'd have to quite the whole thing anyway. Using `:user` doesn't work either, the colon is seen as just another character, it doesn't try to find a column called `user` instead.

The simplest approach may be to pre-process the data file and remove any rows which don't match the pattern (e.g. via a regex). That would actually be slightly easier if you used an external table instead of SQL*Loader.

Alternatively, generate your control file and embed the correct literal value based on the user you'll connect as.